# Public-private function access via component inheritance in ColdFusion

Tags: function, inheritance, coldfusion, encapsulation, cfml

I am experiencing an unexpected issue with ColdFusion Markup Language.  Let's say I have the following components. If both a public and a private function are defined in a "base" component, can the former still invoke the private one when called from an extending "sub" type's instances?

**Program.cfc**

```
<cfcomponent>

    <cffunction access="public" name="doOperation"> 
        <cfset this.checkValue(-14)>
    </cffunction> 


    <cffunction access="private" name="checkValue">
        <cfargument name="notNeg" required="yes" type="numeric">

        <cfif arguments.notNeg LT 0 >
            <cfthrow message="Negative Numbers not allowed"> 
        </cfif>
    </cffunction> 

 </cfcomponent>
```

**SubProgram.cfc**

```
<cfcomponent extends="Program">

</cfcomponent>
```

**Run.cfm**

```
 <cfobject component="SubProgram" name="this.instance">

 <cfset this.instance.doOperation()>                      <<<<----ERROR---->>>>
```

ColdFusion throws the error

> method `checkValue` was not found in component `SubProgram`. Ensure that the method is defined...

What is the issue here? No brownie points for encapsulation!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you're trying to call the `checkValue()` method as a *public* method. `this` does not work in CFML the same way as it does in other languages (a very poor design decision on the part of Macromedia): `this` is an external reference to the object itself, so if you call `this.someMethod()`, that's trying to call a `public` method called `someMethod()` (as if you were calling `myObject.someMethod()`). In CFML parlance, the `variables` scope is the reference to *private* data/members.

What you want to do is this:

```
<cffunction access="public" name="doOperation"> 
    <cfset variables.checkValue(-14)>
</cffunction>
```

Or simply:

```
<cffunction access="public" name="doOperation"> 
    <cfset checkValue(-14)>
</cffunction>
```

Also, if you're using a recent version of CF (eg: CF10 or CF11) you really want to not write your components in tags. It makes for pretty awful-looking code. Try to limit tag usage to view files. CF10 still doesn't have 100% support for all CFML constructs in script, but CF11 does.

Comment: Thanks, I knew I wasn't crazy. BTW it's CF8.

Comment: Ah, OK: stick with tags. You can't upgrade to a still-supported version of CF (eg: 10 or 11?). 8 is a bit rubbish.